# How can I insert a link to tag from tag wikis (NOT excerpt)?

Tags: support, tags, markdown, hyperlinks, tag-wiki

I'd like to make a link to tag (questions tagged) from tag wiki: E.g. link to [questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operating-system) `operating-system`:

[image]

Here is the link to [windows tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows/info).

How can I make such a link?

Comment: In this case, the answer you got below is correct, just use the ordinary tag markdown. It got nothing to do with tag wiki.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, as you can see my question is NOT about "tag wiki excerpt" but about "tag wiki". Please check the image and text before marking as duplicate

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the the wiki description you can use the same markup/markdown as in posts. So `[tag:unicorns]` results in [unicorns](/questions/tagged/unicorns).

Of course, you could always take a look at a tag wiki that has the sort of formatting you want and click "edit" to see how it was done.

Note: The wiki excerpt can *only* contain plain text.

Comment: [tag:status-completed]

Comment: it also works in comments